# IRS letter about 401(k) rollover not shown on return

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, income-tax, rollover-direct

I got an IRS letter that states my return does not match the records they have from others.  In particular, it shows I reported $0 but they were reported a non-zero amount for taxable retirement income from a rollover IRA.  However, in my case, this income is not taxable because I directly rolled it over to my new employer's 401(k). It is listed on my 1040 on line 15a of 2010 1040 with a left column note (put there by TurboTax) that states: "Rollover".

What has gone wrong?  Is it that the target of the rollover did not report receiving the funds or that the sender did not properly report it was a direct rollover?

Comment: When was the rollover? Is it Possible that the money was sent by the first one in late December but arrived at the other one in early January?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep why would that matter? Direct rollover is a transfer between the custodians, its not going through the taxpayers bank account (that's why its called *direct*)

Comment: This is a records match question. If company A sent it on Friday December 30th 2011, it might not get processed until Tuesday January 3rd 2012. Therefore 2 different tax years. The new company wouldn't tell the IRS until January 2013.

Comment: doubt its relevant. Deposits are not reported to the IRS by the new company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to the TurboTax support. Generally, I've heard of several similar reports this year where people with 1099-R that had "G" marked properly got similar notices (direct rollover), and it appears to be a glitch in the IRS programming. If this is the case for you, then a simple response explaining that you reported correctly and attaching the copies of the appropriate forms would suffice.